# OVER QUERY LIMIT only on my wifi

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm using google distance matrix api for calculating distance/time between 1 source and 10 destinations. I know there is quota limit of 2500 request per day. I am always getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT  while using my home wifi for communication. However using cellular data or neighbor wifi, it works. Can someone suggest what could be the possible reason.
I guess there is only per day usage limit, I tried using on different day even then it dint work out

**Update**: I realized that I was calling the distance matrix API after a period of every 2 seconds because of which quote reached up pretty soon (I did not add a check for not calling api if there is not any change in input parameters). Fixed after these changes.

Answer (score 0):

As most Internet users today you're probably behind a NAT. This means that many machines/users are using the same IP address to access the Internet and the NAT remembers who is talking to who and routes the packets  to the right inner machine/user.

Maybe the way you're connected to the Internet shares the same IP address with many other users.